# Javascript is broken in html page source

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a java web application. I am using jquery in it. I am calling some javascript from my jsp page. I have used EL, jstl tag in my page. Some of jquery variables is assigned from jsp variable. A strange problem occurs randomly. Some of javascript line have broken. I found those from Page Source option of browser. But in the jsp page I have found that no code is broken.
Say I have the following line in jsp

```
var iChars = "!@#$%^&*()+=-[]\\\';,./{}|\":<>?~_";
var term = $.trim(request.term.toLowerCase());
var wordCount = term.split(" ").length;

if (term.length > 0 && iChars.indexOf(term.charAt(0)) == -1) {
    // here a jquery ajax call
}
else if (term.length > 0 && iChars.indexOf(term.charAt(0)) != -1) {
   $("#simpleSearch-1105 .field").autocomplete("close");
   alert("Search word should not start with !@#$%^&*()+=-[]\\\';,./{}|\":<>?~_");
}
```

But in the html page source I found the line as follows

```
$("#simpleSearch-
1105 .field").autocomplete("close");
```

The code is broken to two line. For this getting js error. I found no valid reason for that. It seems completely strange to me. Could you guys can give me some clue ? Whats may be the cause ?

Note: I also have firebug installed. First I thought that it may be due to firebug. Then I uninstalled firebug. But still same result.

Comment: Could be due to the hyphen (-) character? Try to change the id of you element removing that both in markup and on jquery selector

Comment: I tried by removing hyphen. But id does not work also. Interesting fact is that if I provide 4/5 empty new line before the javascript code then it is showing no js error.

Comment: Can you post a little more of the code context, ie, the 20 lines surrounding '$("#simpleSearch-1105 .field").autocomplete("close");'?

Comment: Question edited for Joe Coder

Comment: Perhaps an IDE bug ... try to copy, remove and paste all the code in a new file.

Comment: @MAKRipon If you find the answer to your question, can you please post it. I'm having the similar issue. Thanks